# Polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, relationship, polymorphic-associations

my problem is in generating a record of a partner within a company with a polymorphic migration.
The partner comes from my collection of users.

This is my form

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @partner], remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'Selecciona un socio' %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:partnershipable_id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Selecciona'}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

my models are

app/models/partner

```
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :partnershipable, polymorphic: true
end
```

app/models/user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many   :partners, as: :partnershipable
end
```

app/models/company

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many    :partners, as: :partnershipable
end
```

how the form should look to save the user correctly as a partner.

Comment: Could you provide more info, like the error or expected behavior with a small example @Esteban Navarro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a polymophic association you need to provide a type as well.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @partner], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'Selecciona un socio' %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:partnershipable_id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Selecciona'}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
    <%= f.hidden_input(:partnershipable_type, 'User') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Since the type appears to be fixed I you could probally set the value in the controller on the recieving end as well.

Comment: I just realized that in addition to User I should be able to add another type "Company"
How do I do it so I can take one or the other?

Comment: Create a partial and pass a local variable (or two) instead of instance variables.